# NServiceBus License File for Dev Machine (keeps requesting)

Tags: nservicebus

I've been using NServiceBus successfully for I don't know how long. The license claimed to expire and informed me that I needed a new license file. So I went to the website and generated a new one (For a dev machine). Everytime I debug I get the same message and it requests the license file. Is there any way to prevent this message from showing up EVERY time I try to debug? (Like set a path programmatically possibly?)

[image: LicenseFile]
<

Andreas : The ONLY mention of the license in the log file is as follows :

```
2013-03-05 14:24:23,983 [1] [INFO ] [NServiceBus.Licensing.LicenseManager] - No valid license found.
2013-03-05 14:24:23,986 [1] [DEBUG] [NServiceBus.Licensing.LicenseManager] - Trial for NServiceBus v3.3 has expired.
2013-03-05 14:24:23,988 [1] [WARN ] [NServiceBus.Licensing.LicenseManager] - Falling back to run in Basic1 license mode.
```

Here's a quick screen capture of the prompt after I select the new file. Just so you know it's SAYING it's a valid file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this can also happen if your license is for a different version of the software than you are running.  You may need to request a license that aligns with your NSB version.

Comment: Well what's funny is I always just click the "Get a free license" button (well not always but every few days). So I don't know how that could be the case (assuming the version # is included in the details that are being sent up at that time). But I'll definitely look into it.

Comment: The website has been updated to generate 4.0 dev licenses. Did you happen to run on the 4.0 nsb binaries?

Comment: @AndreasÖhlund I talked to my old team lead (changed jobs) and we were running 3.3 at the time.

Answer (score 1):

Once you received your free license, did you import it?
You need to click the "Browse..." button and select the license to import it!

Comment: Yep definitely did that :) And it disappears... until I debug again. It's very strange.

Comment: The message is only displayed in debug mode. Turn on INFO logging and make sure that the enpoint reports that it picked the license up?

Comment: @AndreasÖhlund I updated the question to include more details (btw I'm running logging on ALL right now)

Comment: @TonyAshworth send an email to get-help@nservicebus.com and refer to this post, I'll contact you via email.

Comment: @JohnSimons I changed jobs & am no longer running nservicebus. Thank you and sorry for the late reply. This was my 2nd implementation though and I suspect not my last.

Comment: @AndreasÖhlund the only workable solution to this issue at the time is part of your answer above. "The message is only displayed in debug mode". My team lead switched to running the app NOT in the debugger and just attaching when he wanted to debug something. This stopped the message from showing up and annoying devs. Can you make that into a separate answer so I can approve it?